# android update version by requesting to server or receiving push by server

Tags: android, push

I want to find a elegant way to update my app version,now there are two known ways that could satisfy my need,but which is the best one and why?

1.Make a request to server each time the app launch,and check the versionName or versionCode;
2.Receive the push message by server;

Comment: Application will be automatically updated by Google Play. But if you want to notify user that he has to update the app I would suggest using version check on the server side since with Push notifications you can't be absolutely sure that user receives it

Comment: @Chaosit,but what if my application not in Google Play?

Comment: Then the second part of my comment should work